# My quicksort code overflows the stack

Tags: c++, sorting, stack-overflow, quicksort

The code works good for small `num_items`, but overflows the stack for `num_items = 1000`.

I think 1000 is a pretty small number, so there should be a way to make this work upto much larger numbers. What can I do to make it survive more recursive calls?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void printv(std::vector<int>& v) {
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void quicksort(std::vector<int>& v, int begin, int end) {

    if (((end - begin) <= 1) ||
        (begin < 0) ||
        (end > (v.size() - 1))) return;

    int pivot = v[std::rand() % v.size()];

    int x = 0;
    int y = v.size() -1;

    while(x < y) {
        int changed = 0;
        if(v[x] <= pivot) {
            x++;
            changed = 1;
        }
        if (v[y] > pivot) {
            y--;
            changed = 1;
        }
        if (!changed){
            std::swap(v[x], v[y]);
            x++;
            y--;
        }
    }

    if (x == y) y++;
    if (x > y) std::swap(x, y);

    quicksort(v, begin, x);
    quicksort(v, y, end);
}

int ran() {
    return std::rand() % 100;
}

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    int num_items = 1000;
    std::vector<int> v (num_items);
    std::generate_n(v.begin(), num_items, ran);

    printv(v);
    quicksort(v, 0, v.size()-1);
    printv(v);
}
```

General comments about the code are also welcome.

---

Stuck at `[0,4]`:

```
#1  0x0000000000400b4c in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:14
#2  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
#3  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
#4  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
#5  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
#6  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
#7  0x0000000000400cc1 in quicksort (
    v=std::vector of length 1000, capacity 1000 = {...}, begin=0, end=4)
    at quicksort.cpp:43
```

Comment: Any specific reason why http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort is not usable instead of your code?

Comment: yes => learning to implement qsort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int pivot = v[std::rand() % v.size()];

int x = 0;
int y = v.size() -1;
```

You explicitly pass `begin` and `end` positions, and yet you choose the pivot element from the complete list. That doesn't sound right. You should choose a pivot element between `begin` and `end`. Also, `x` should start at `begin`, and `y` should start at `end`. Otherwise, you are always processing the complete list in each recursive step, which would explain the infinite recursion you are experiencing.

Comment: Just noticed that he chooses pivot from the whole list as well, didn't notice the other issues tough, well done

Comment: You gotta get that name on business cards, sir.

Comment: @WhozCraig me or FredOverflow?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed these. Looks like there is one more problem in the for loop, it is recursing forever on `[begin=0, end=4]`. Looking into it.

Comment: @xception Fred, though your's is almost a mantra and not just a name.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Any suggestions for handling the case where all the elements lie on one side of the pivot?

As I understand, it can happen due to two reasons - 1. all the elements are the same (in which case we need to stop recursion), and 2. the pivot is the least element of the set (in which case the recursion needs to go on). How to correctly handle these two?

Comment: Your code contains a lot of logic that I have never seen in Quicksort code. I could post working code that is much simpler, but I doubt that would help you learn anything. I learned about different Quicksort implementations with varying trade-offs from the book "Programming Pearls" which I highly recommend.